# Probability of having the same birthday

Tags: probability

I just recently discovered that I share my birthday with a friend at school. I've been wondering what the probability of that happening is. The population of my country is 182.1 million, the population of my city
 is 23.5 million and the population of my school is 1500. How do I start?

Comment: For a reasonable estimate, one would need the number of friends.

Comment: The number of people I know in the school or the total number of people I know?

Comment: It depends on the question you are asking. If you want the probability that you have a friend at school that you share a birthday with, one needs to know the number of friends you have. To compute the probability someone you know has the same birthday as you, we need the number of people you know.

Comment: oh okay. so how do I go about calculating the probability?

Comment: If you have $k$ friends, then a reasonable estimate for the probability at least one of your friends has the same birthday as you is $1-\left(\frac{364}{365}\right)^k$.

Comment: And how why would I calculate the probability that $only$ $d$ number of my friends have the same birthday as me?

Comment: Do you mean exactly $d$? A reasonable model would be binomial, $p=1/365$, $n$ the number of friends you have. So $\binom{n}{d}(1/365)^d(364/365)^{n-d}$.

Comment: yes. Could you explain how you arrived at that formula?

Comment: Explanation would very much depend on the mathematical background you have, and would be very lengthy if you have little knowledge of probability. You might look up Binomial Distribution on Wikipedia. The level may be inappropriate.

Comment: I am a high school student in my final year.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a "real-world" problem, so at best we can make an estimate based on a reasonable set of assumptions. For example, if your birthday is on February $29$, the answer depends very much on the range of ages of your friends.

Let us construct a *mathematical model* of the situation. We assume that the year has $365$ days (not quite true) and that birthdays are uniformly distributed over the year. This again is not quite true, the distribution is not uniform, and there is some variation from country to country. We also assume that your choice of friends is birthday-independent.

If we pick one of your friends at random, the probability that he/she has a birthday *different* from yours is $\frac{364}{365}$. So if you have $n$ friends, by independence the probability they *all* have birthdays different from yours is $\left(\frac{364}{365}\right)^n$. Thus the probability that at least one of your friends has the same birthday as yours is $1-\left(\frac{364}{365}\right)^n$.